# how to compute the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored for a float number

Tags: python

I was looking into [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), it says

if Python were to print the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored for 0.1, it would have to display

```
>>> 0.1
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

my question is, is there an existing API I can use to get the long string value?

or I have to do this manully? like

```
target = 0.1
tem = 0.0
for i in range(-1, -307, -1):
    if (2 ** i < target):
        if (tem + 2 ** i < target):
            tem += 2 ** i
            print(i)
        else:
            break
```

this code block is just to demonstrate what I want to get.

I searched inside SO, found people just cite the doc without provide an implementation.

Comment: `print('{:.53f}'.format(target))`

Comment: BTW, computers work in binary, so in a sense, the binary value is the float's true value, the decimal representation is the approximation. ;)

Comment: @PM. Since binary fractions are always non-repeating in decimal, what OP is asking for is very much the true value stored in the binary

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this from my own Google search and found the solution elsewhere (and mentioned by @PM 2RING here).

```
a = ('{:.53f}'.format(target))
```

The format option allows you to force the variable to explicitly contain 53 decimal points and then store this as a string.